# How to make changes to an existing website using acquia dev (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, acquia

We had a website built with Drupal which is not live anymore. Now we have to modify the text content in the site. The files and the database dump are compressed and are available. I was able to successfully import this site in to my  aqcuia desktop setup.
Could some please tell me how do I modify the content of this site on my local setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I just started using Drupal , was not aware that i have to login as an admin and then start editing.
To get to the admin login page , append /user/login to the site domain name.
For ex: www.domian.com/user/login
Once you login as admin, the site goes in to editable mode.